# Persistir o mesmo registro por usuario diferentes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu já vi que tem como, porém não me lembro como faz e nem uma palavra chave para eu pesquisar.

Suponhamos que usuários distintos editem o mesmo registro, quando o último usuário for persistir as informações no banco, quero mostrar uma mensagem que esse registro já foi alterado por outro usuário.

Alguém sabe como faz ou uma palavra chave para eu poder pesquisar?

Answer (score 0):

- Atomicidade – As operações de uma transação só serão persistidas (COMMIT) se todas elas forem executadas com sucesso. Caso ocorram falhas, todas as operações da transação serão canceladas (ROLLBACK).
- Consistência – As transações devem respeitas as regras de integridade do banco, como chaves primárias, chaves estrangeiras, dentre outras, persistindo apenas dados válidos.
- Isolamento – Uma transação não pode sofrer interferências de transações concorrentes.
- Durabilidade – Quando uma transação é confirmada (COMMIT) os dados serão persistidos no banco, e podem ser recuperados.

Acredito que isso é o que preciso. Caso alguém, algum dia procure talvez ajude.

Comment: Esse linq é o que estava procurando: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application